# react-native-code-push:compiledebugjavawithjavac failed with react-native 0.66.4

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

I have created two application, the first one was with `react-native 0.65.1` and the second one with `react-native 0.66.4`

before putting my apps on play store I decide to integrate `react-native-code-push` . every thing work with the first app `react-native 0.65.1` but when I follow the same steps to integrate `code-push` in the second app `react-native 0.66.4` I got this error after running `npx react-native run-android`
the error:

```
> Task :react-native-code-push:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

I tried to run `cd android && ./gradlew clean` but it doesn't work.

code-push version in my two projects is: `"react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4"`